# Mysql query -- choosing highest rank/ordered subject in table (join)

Tags: mysql, sql

Scenario:

We have 5 users. (users table)
Each user has up to 10 imgs. (image table)
These 10 images can be ordered 1 – 10. (image table)
Each img can be listed in multiple categories (say there are 5 categories – birds, bees, bunnies, brains, belugas (category table connected to img table via table that stores img_ids and category_ids)

In searching through the categories, say someone chooses bees. The search should find the images in that category that is listed CLOSEST to the #1 img for all users.  So if each user has 3 images in the bees category, ordered as numbers 4, 7 & 9, the search should show the 4th as its closest to the number 1.

The results I keep getting are all over the place and almost seems like it is choosing the images via WHEN they were added to the DB.

```
SELECT i.img_name, i.ordered, a.user_name, c.keyword, c.cat_id
FROM images AS i JOIN artists AS a USING (user_id) 
JOIN img_cat_table AS im USING ( img_id )
JOIN catkeys AS c USING (cat_id)
WHERE ( cat_id = 3) // THE BEES ID # 
    GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_name DESC
```

Comment: Is user_img the user's ranking of the image (ie. the field you want to sort on)?

Comment: can you post an outline of the tables?

Comment: @ Mark B -- sorry that was a typo. Its just ordering them by the user name (alphabetically).

Comment: @ Ben -- would a mysql workbench layout help? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not sure if you want to show all of the relevant images in the right order, or only the top one. Assuming that it is the latter situation, you will need to join to a subquery or view that returns the min rank for each user, category:

```
SELECT i.img_name, i.ordered, a.user_name, c.keyword, c.cat_id
FROM images AS i JOIN artists AS a USING (user_id) 
JOIN img_cat_table AS im USING ( img_id )
JOIN catkeys AS c USING (cat_id)
JOIN (
SELECT user_id, min(img_rank) img_rank
FROM images AS i 
JOIN artists AS a on i.user_id = a.user_id
JOIN img_cat_table AS im on im.img_id = i.img_id
JOIN catkeys AS c on c.cat_id = i.cat_id
WHERE ( cat_id = 3) ) x on x.user_id = a.user_id and x.img_rank = img_rank
WHERE c.cat_id = 3
```

I'm not sure what the name of the column that holds the image ranking is. I called it img_rank. Hopefully this will give you the idea

Comment: Only looking to pull the top one for each user img in that category. (hope that made sense)

Comment: Yeah, then you will need a subquery like the one I wrote above. I edited my answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

though if you can post the table structure and data, that will be great but Here is what I haved tried

```
SELECT i.img_name, i.ordered, a.user_name, c.keyword, c.cat_id
from (
select img_name, ordered, img_id, user_id from 
images 
group by user_id
order by user_img ) as i
JOIN artists AS a USING (user_id) 
JOIN img_cat_table AS im USING ( img_id )
JOIN catkeys AS c USING (cat_id)
WHERE ( cat_id = 3) // THE BEES ID #
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing DESC from your ORDER BY clause.